# The use of the adjective "taken" in context

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Suppose I am in a hostel's kitchen; a guy takes a plate from a cupboard and asks me to save it for him in case somebody needs the plate while he is out. And then another guy comes up to take a plate.

Is it natural to use the adjective *taken* in the context? For example:

> I am sorry, but the plate is **taken**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, very natural.

The only change I'd make is

> I am sorry, but *this* plate is taken.

so you can refer directly to that specific plate.

Comment: Not usual at all to say this. But it is grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of keeping something or reserving something, anything pretty much can be taken/

- this seat is taken
- this plate is taken

Generally, though a plate is not reserved for someone's use....

Comment: The usual expectation is that once you take a plate out of the stack, it's for your use only. If there are no more plates, someone else should not take yours.

Comment: Who says there is a stack of plates? They could be laid out on a table at place settings.

Comment: It would be incredibly rude or weird for someone to take the plate from someone else's place setting (unless they're removing a plate after you've eaten). When you take a seat, you essentially "own" the whole place setting. The napkin, silverware, plates, etc. are all "taken".

Comment: If you take a plate out of a stack, it is already in your hand. Therefore,it does not make sense to **then say**: This **plate** is taken, generally speaking.

Comment: You might put it down somewhere. The sentence in the question is obviously based on a situation where someone else can try to use your plate.

Comment: @Barmar And then you'd most likely say: That's my plate. And not This plate is taken, which is really not a usual statement. Seats are taken.

Comment: There are lots of different ways to say things like this, it depends on the person. You would also say "That's my seat".

Comment: My original comment in my answer is correct. We don't usually go around saying: This **plate** is **taken**.